# What does it mean when Android ADT is unsigned (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm having severe problems with the Android development tools in Eclipse. I went to check my plugins and it indicates that my ADT is unsigned. I have a feeling this is the root of my problems. But I dont know how or why it is unsigned since I haven't updated it and I havent changed anything to do with it for a couple of months, while still developing Adnroid apps.

Has anyone else had this problem? What should I do?

Comment: i'm just guessing... this may be something new in Eclipse Juno... I also got the warning. android ADT install page http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html does not mention it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at my 'Installed Software - Plugins', I see that all 3 components of the ADT are unsigned too. The Subversion and Tomcat plugins are unsigned as well.

I don't believe that this is a problem for me, as the ADT works fine. I think the provider just didn't sign them.

Comment: i think the question is to understand what does that 'signing' mean. when was that introduced. who controls the keys. who accepts what's signed and what's not. and more importantly, SHOULD those packages have been signed and we 3 are not getting them in the signed form?

Comment: From the Google docs http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html, 
 "7 Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK." It's not signed because it's not signed because they didn't sign it. So just check things before you downvote accepted answers